# Rank based on several variables

Tags: r, dplyr, ranking, rank

This is a small example.  In my larger dataset, I have multiple years of data and the number of observations per group (div) are not always equal.

Example data:

```
set.seed(1)
df<-data.frame(
  year = 2014,
  id = sample(LETTERS[1:26], 12),
  div = rep(c("1", "2a", "2b"), each=4),
  pts = c(9,7,9,3,7,5,3,7,2,7,7,1),
  x = c(10,12,11,7,7,5,4,12,4,6,7,2)
)
```

df

```
#   year id div pts  x
#1  2014  G   1   9 10
#2  2014  J   1   7 12
#3  2014  N   1   9 11
#4  2014  U   1   3  7
#5  2014  E  2a   7  7
#6  2014  S  2a   5  5
#7  2014  W  2a   3  4
#8  2014  M  2a   7 12
#9  2014  L  2b   2  4
#10 2014  B  2b   7  6
#11 2014  D  2b   7  7
#12 2014  C  2b   1  2
```

I want to rank this data such that individuals in div 1 are ranked higher than div 2a/2b, and within div 1 individuals are ranked 1,2,3,4 based on highest number of 'pts' followed by highest number of 'x'.

Individuals in div 2a and div 2b should be ranked individually also based on the same criteria.  This would look like this:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(div) %>%
  arrange(desc(pts), desc(x)) %>%
  mutate(position = row_number(div))


#   year id div pts  x position
#1  2014  N   1   9 11        1
#2  2014  G   1   9 10        2
#3  2014  J   1   7 12        3
#4  2014  U   1   3  7        4
#5  2014  M  2a   7 12        1
#6  2014  E  2a   7  7        2
#7  2014  S  2a   5  5        3
#8  2014  W  2a   3  4        4
#9  2014  D  2b   7  7        1
#10 2014  B  2b   7  6        2
#11 2014  L  2b   2  4        3
#12 2014  C  2b   1  2        4
```

However, I want to produce a final column/variable that is another rank.  This would rank all individuals in div 1 as higher than 2a/2b, but 2a/2b are equal. i.e. individuals who are 1 in 2a/2b should now get 5.5, individuals who are ranked 2 should now get 7.5.    There are always an equal number of individuals in div2a and div2b for all years.

It should look like this:

```
#   year id div pts  x position final
#1  2014  N   1   9 11        1   1.0  
#2  2014  G   1   9 10        2   2.0
#3  2014  J   1   7 12        3   3.0
#4  2014  U   1   3  7        4   4.0
#5  2014  M  2a   7 12        1   5.5
#6  2014  E  2a   7  7        2   7.5
#7  2014  S  2a   5  5        3   9.5
#8  2014  W  2a   3  4        4  11.5
#9  2014  D  2b   7  7        1   5.5
#10 2014  B  2b   7  6        2   7.5  
#11 2014  L  2b   2  4        3   9.5
#12 2014  C  2b   1  2        4  11.5
```

I need to find a `dplyr` solution ideally.   Also, it does need to generalize to years where the number of individuals in 'div1' may vary and the number of individuals in div2a/div2b varies (although length(div2a)==length(div2b) always).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is how I'd do it:

```
library(data.table)
dt = as.data.table(df)

dt[order(-pts, -x), rank.init := 1:.N, by = div]

dt[, div.clean := sub('(\\d+).*', '\\1', div)]
setorder(dt, div.clean, rank.init)

dt[, rank.final := mean(.I), by = .(div.clean, rank.init)]
setorder(dt, div, rank.final)
#    year id div pts  x rank.init div.clean rank.final
# 1: 2014  N   1   9 11         1         1        1.0
# 2: 2014  G   1   9 10         2         1        2.0
# 3: 2014  J   1   7 12         3         1        3.0
# 4: 2014  U   1   3  7         4         1        4.0
# 5: 2014  M  2a   7 12         1         2        5.5
# 6: 2014  E  2a   7  7         2         2        7.5
# 7: 2014  S  2a   5  5         3         2        9.5
# 8: 2014  W  2a   3  4         4         2       11.5
# 9: 2014  D  2b   7  7         1         2        5.5
#10: 2014  B  2b   7  6         2         2        7.5
#11: 2014  L  2b   2  4         3         2        9.5
#12: 2014  C  2b   1  2         4         2       11.5
```

Comment: Thanks - both answers are great.  Problems like this encourage me to get more familiar with `data.table`

Comment: also - just  a clarification, if wanting to perform this for multiple years simultaneously in the same dt, would the `by = div` need to be `by = .(div,year)` ?

Comment: @jalapic yes, and you may need to modify the last `mean`, depending on what exactly you want done for multiple years

Answer (score 6):

@eddi's answer is already very nice. I just wanted to illustrate the same using `frank()` function from the development version of `data.table, v1.9.5`, which can compute ranks on vectors, lists, data.frames or data.tables.

```
# from @eddi's
setDT(df)[, div.clean := sub('(\\d+).*', '\\1', div)]

df[, position := frank(.SD, -pts, -x, ties.method="first"), by=div]
df[, final := frank(.SD, div.clean, position, ties.method="average")]
```

This also retains the original order, if that's of any importance.

I'll leave the conversion to `dplyr` to you.