# Using multiple columns in dplyr window functions?

Tags: r, dplyr, window-functions

Comming from SQL i would expect i was able to do something like the following in dplyr, is this possible?

```
# R
tbl %>% mutate(n = dense_rank(Name, Email))

-- SQL
SELECT Name, Email, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Name, Email) AS n FROM tbl
```

Also is there an equivilant for `PARTITION BY`?

Comment: like this `mtcars %>% mutate(n = dense_rank(interaction(cyl, hp)))`?

Comment: @docendodiscimus thats awesome, had completly forgotten about `interaction()` i had hashed the values but that messes up the order.
Is there any easy solution for using `PARTITION BY`?

Comment: I don't know what that does

Comment: @CodeMonkey - If you're thinking `PARTITION BY` to get a ranking by group, you would use a `group by` in dplyr. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34967837/rank-variable-by-group-dplyr

Comment: @Jason Awesome! its working. Using interaction with `lex.order` one can almost simulate the OVER(ORDER BY) and group_by works like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did struggle with this problem and here is my solution:

In case you can't find any function which supports ordering by multiple variables, I suggest that you concatenate them by their priority level from left to right using `paste()`.

Below is the code sample:

```
tbl %>%
  mutate(n = dense_rank(paste(Name, Email))) %>%
  arrange(Name, Email) %>%
  view()
```

Moreover, I guess group_by is the equivalent for PARTITION BY in SQL.

The shortfall for this solution is that you can only order by 2 (or more) variables which have the same direction. In the case that you need to order by multiple columns which have different direction, saying that 1 asc and 1 desc, I suggest you to try this:
[Calculate rank with ties based on more than one variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45917470/calculate-rank-with-ties-based-on-more-than-one-variable)

Comment: The example you propose differs from the one asked. Try updating it to match the example provided by the question creator.

Comment: Hi Bao if you fix your answer i can set it as accepted.