# Dense Rank by Multiple Columns in R

Tags: r, dplyr

How can I get a dense rank of multiple columns in a dataframe? For example,

```
# I have:
df <- data.frame(x = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3), 
                 y = c(1,2,3,4,2,2,2,1,2,3))
# I want:
res <- data.frame(x = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3), 
                  y = c(1,2,3,4,2,2,2,1,2,3),
                  r = c(1,2,3,4,5,5,5,6,7,8))
res
   x y z
1  1 1 1
2  1 2 2
3  1 3 3
4  1 4 4
5  2 2 5
6  2 2 5
7  2 2 5
8  3 1 6
9  3 2 7
10 3 3 8
```

My hack approach works for this particular dataset:

```
df %>%
  arrange(x,y) %>%
  mutate(r = if_else(y - lag(y,default=0) == 0, 0, 1)) %>%
  mutate(r = cumsum(r))
```

But there must be a more general solution, maybe using functions like `dense_rank()` or `row_number()`. But I'm struggling with this.

`dplyr` solutions are ideal.

Comment: Do you want to rank the rows? Or do you want a dense rank in the sense that there are no gaps?

Comment: So there are no gaps

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer and then check mark it a few days later. Someone may come by asking in the same way as you.,

Comment: I made the edits. Thx!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48337259/using-multiple-columns-in-dplyr-window-functions). In my case, it would be:

```
mutate(df, r = dense_rank(interaction(x,y,lex.order=T)))
```

Answer (score 7):

### data.table

`data.table` has you covered with `frank()`.

```
library(data.table)    
frank(df, x,y, ties.method = 'min')

[1]  1  2  3  4  5  5  5  8  9 10
```

You can `df$r <- frank(df, x,y, ties.method = 'min')` to add as a new column.

### tidyr/dplyr

Another option (though clunkier) is to use `tidyr::unite` to collapse your columns to one plus `dplyr::dense_rank`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%

  # add a single column with all the info
  unite(xy, x, y) %>%
  cbind(df) %>%

  # dense rank on that
  mutate(r = dense_rank(xy)) %>%

  # now drop the helper col
  select(-xy)
```

Comment: Love the `data.table` solution. Time for me to get on board with that package. The `tidyverse` solution isn't quite general enough for me. E.g., if we used `df2 <- data.frame(x = c(1,1,1,1,20,20,20,3,3,3), y = c(1,2,3,4,20,20,20,1,2,3))` in place of `df`, we'd get the same rank `r` from above. But we we should get is `r2 <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,8,8)`. So the `tidyverse` solution won't generally work for numbers with varying digits. But I didn't specify in my question the generality I was looking for.

Comment: Also, for your `tidyverse` solution you can use `unite(xy, x, y, drop=F)` and eliminate the `cbind(df)` row. Saves a line of code :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple dplyr approach.  Use percent_rank (generalizable to as many additional columns as you want, just multiply the first sort column by the highest power of ten).  Then use dense_rank on the overall sum.  This gives you more control on how each column is handled.  You could specify the z sort to be descending, for example.

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(3,3,3,3,6,6,6,8,8,8), 
                 y = c(5,6,7,8,4,4,4,2,3,7),
                 z = c(1,1,5,1,3,3,2,5,5,1))

df %>% mutate(r = dense_rank((percent_rank(x)*90+10)+(percent_rank(y)*9+1)+percent_rank(desc(z))))

#  x y z r
#  3 5 1 1
#  3 6 1 2
#  3 7 5 3
#  3 8 1 4
#  6 4 3 5
#  6 4 3 5
#  6 4 2 6
#  8 2 5 7
#  8 3 5 8
#  8 7 1 9
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cur_group_id`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(x, y) %>% 
  mutate(r = cur_group_id())

# x     y     r
# <dbl> <dbl> <int>
# 1     1     1     1
# 2     1     2     2
# 3     1     3     3
# 4     1     4     4
# 5     2     2     5
# 6     2     2     5
# 7     2     2     5
# 8     3     1     6
# 9     3     2     7
# 10    3     3     8
```