# How do you rank a dataframe over multiple columns?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, ranking

I'd like to add a (dense) rank column to my dataframe based on multiple other columns, like `rank() over (order by a, b)` in SQL. In R, the `rank` function only accepts one column, so `mutate(df, rank(a, b))` throws an error. The `order_by` function also only accepts one column.

So given this data frame:

```
d <- data.frame(a = c(1, 1, 1, 2), b = c(1, 1, 2, 2))
```

...I'd like a rank like the following:

```
 a  b  rank
 1  1  1 
 1  1  1 
 1  2  2 
 2  2  3
```

My actual dataframe is much larger and the ranking needs to be over multiple columns of different types (mostly strings and doubles).

Comment: If you are happy to leave the `verse`, you may use `data.table::frank(d, ties.method = "dense")`. `?frank`: "Similar to `base::rank` but much faster. And it accepts vectors, lists, data.frames or data.tables as input [...] If `...` is missing, all columns are considered by default. To sort by a column in descending order prefix "`-`", e.g., `frank(x, a, -b, c)`.

Comment: The lack of `dplyr` answers here [dplyr ranking observations across variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28588971/dplyr-ranking-observations-across-variables) and here [Calculate rank with ties based on more than one variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45917470/calculate-rank-with-ties-based-on-more-than-one-variable) suggests that it may not be straightforward in `dplyr`.

Comment: Consider that `rank(x)` is much similar to `order(order(x))` and the latter can be applied to multiple vectors. For instance, if `x` is a `list` or `data.frame`,  you could try `order(do.call(order,x))`.

Comment: In this case because a and b are both numbers under 10, you can use `mutate(df, rank = dense_rank(10*a + b))`