# Calculate rank based on several columns, with a precedence rule

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, ranking, rank

I have a dataframe like this

```
df <- expand.grid(0:1, 0:1, 0:1, 0:1)
df
   Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4
1     0    0    0    0
2     1    0    0    0
3     0    1    0    0
4     1    1    0    0
5     0    0    1    0
6     1    0    1    0
7     0    1    1    0
8     1    1    1    0
9     0    0    0    1
10    1    0    0    1
11    0    1    0    1
12    1    1    0    1
13    0    0    1    1
14    1    0    1    1
15    0    1    1    1
16    1    1    1    1
```

I am trying to create a `Rank` column based on some conditions on `Var1, Var2, Var3, Var4`

The order of ranking precedence is determined by the variables

- Column **Var1** has the highest preference and if it has a value of 1, then it is given a higher rank
- Column **Var2** has a higher preference over **Var3**, **Var4**
- Columns **Var1** and **Var2** have higher preference over **Var3**, **Var4**
- There is NO preference given to **Var3** and **Var4** and are only used as counts for ranking

If any rows have the same counts for **Var3**, **Var4**, then they are ranked with the same number.

My **desired output** is

```
   Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4 rank
1     0    0    0    0   12
2     1    0    0    0    6
3     0    1    0    0    9
4     1    1    0    0    3
5     0    0    1    0   11
6     1    0    1    0    5
7     0    1    1    0    8
8     1    1    1    0    2
9     0    0    0    1   11
10    1    0    0    1    5
11    0    1    0    1    8
12    1    1    0    1    2
13    0    0    1    1   10
14    1    0    1    1    4
15    0    1    1    1    7
16    1    1    1    1    1
```

I am trying to this manually but it is not very efficient

```
df %>%
  mutate(rank = case_when(
    Var1 == 1 & Var2 == 1 & Var3 == 1 & Var4 == 1~ "1",
    Var1 == 1 & Var2 == 1 & Var3 == 1 & Var4 == 0~ "2",
    TRUE                                     ~ ""
  ))
```

I want to apply the logic to a larger dataset. Is there an efficient way to do this? Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`frank` and `frankv` in `data.table` "*accepts vectors, lists, data.frames or data.tables as input*", which can be useful here.

First, `frankv`. It has a `cols` argument where columns to be ranked can be specified in a character vector - convenient if there are many column names which need to be generated programmatically. It also has a neat `order` argument.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[ , Var34 := Var3 + Var4]
cols = c("Var1", "Var2", "Var34")
df[ , r := frankv(.SD, cols, order = -1L, ties.method = "dense")]
df[ , Var34 := NULL]

#     Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4  r
#  1:    0    0    0    0 12
#  2:    1    0    0    0  6
#  3:    0    1    0    0  9
#  4:    1    1    0    0  3
#  5:    0    0    1    0 11
#  6:    1    0    1    0  5
#  7:    0    1    1    0  8
#  8:    1    1    1    0  2
#  9:    0    0    0    1 11
# 10:    1    0    0    1  5
# 11:    0    1    0    1  8
# 12:    1    1    0    1  2
# 13:    0    0    1    1 10
# 14:    1    0    1    1  4
# 15:    0    1    1    1  7
# 16:    1    1    1    1  1
```

`frank` is handy for interactive use:

```
df[ , r := frank(.SD, -Var1, -Var2, -Var34, ties.method = "dense")]
```

---

Related answers: [How to emulate SQLs rank functions in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11446254/how-to-emulate-sqls-rank-functions-in-r/28141041#28141041); [Rank based on several variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28588971/rank-based-on-several-variables/28590330#28590330)

Comment: Thanks for this solution :-)  data.table continues to amaze me with its simplicity and execution. I am now applying your logic to my large data frame. I will report back

Comment: It works perfectly on my bigger dataset. Thank you so much :-)

Answer (score 0):

I propose this which is a small trick :

```
df <- expand.grid(0:1, 0:1, 0:1, 0:1)

df[,2] <- df[,2] * 10
df[,3] <- df[,3] * 100
df[,4] <- df[,4] * 100

rank <- rowSums(df)
as.numeric(as.factor(rank))
```

Comment: FYI `apply(df, 1, sum)` is equivalent to `rowSums(df)`